# Confirm if subOU already exist?

Tags: powershell

Hello i am trying to create a script that creates sub OU, before i inserted the if statement everything worked fine.
If the OU' already exist, i want the script to write the warning.
I think the error is within the if statement, and tried different methods to no avail.
Anybody got any bright ideas? thanks.

```
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "ou1" -Path "OU=mylab,DC=mylab,DC=local"
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "ou2" -Path "OU=mylab,DC=mylab,DC=local"
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "ou3" -Path "OU=mylac,DC=mylab,DC=local"

$ou1 = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -like "ou1"'
$ou2 = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -like "ou2"'
$ou3 = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -like "ou3"'
$ouall = $ou1, $ou2, $ou3
$ouall

foreach ($ou in $ouall){
    If(Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter "Name -eq '$ou'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
        Write-Warning "This Ou already exists"
    }
    Else{
        Write-Host $ou.DistinguishedName
        New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "Users" -Path $ou.DistinguishedName
        New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "Computers" -Path $ou.DistinguishedName
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be simplified quite a bit. If they are indeed going into the same root path then this is how I'd do it. I don't see the need to get the distinguished name of existing OUs because you are only creating if they don't exist and they won't be created in themselves.

```
$ous = "ou1","ou2","ou3"

$ous | ForEach-Object {
    If(Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter "Name -eq '$_'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
        Write-Warning "OU $_ already exists"
    }
    else{
        Write-host creating OU $_
        New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name $_ -Path "OU=mylab,DC=mylab,DC=local"
    }
}
```

The main issue in your if statement previously is that you are checking if name -eq $ou where $ou would be an OU object, not a name.